# Can we apply Lusin's Theorem to $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}\,$?

Tags: real-analysis

Lusin's Theorem implies that if $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable real-valued function on $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=0$ outside a set $A$ of finite Lebesgue measure $m$, and if $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, then there exists a continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb R$ that has compact support and such that
$$
m\left(x\in\mathbb R\colon\ f(x)\neq g(x)\right)<\epsilon.
$$

> Does this theorem apply to the function $f$ that is the characteristic function of the set of all rationals $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$? If it does apply, state what the function $g$ is.

I am studying Rudin's RCA book chapter 2 and trying to proof this. Per my understanding, we can apply Lusin's theorem to a function if that function is measurable, and is zero outside a set of finite measure.

In this problem, $f$ is characteristic of the set $\mathbb Q$. So $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is not in $\mathbb Q$, and m($\mathbb Q$) is zero.

I am having trouble to show $f$ is a measurable function, and to show what function $g$ is.

Do I have to show $\mathbb Q$ is a measurable set? How can I show this? Please anyone help me; your help will be appreciated.

Comment: $g=0$ is continuous and Lebesgue-a.e. equal to the characteristic function of the rationals

Comment: The set of rational numbers is measurable because it is a countable union of singletons, which are trivially measurable.

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Comment: Once again (my personaly peeve): In math "proof" is a noun, and "to prove" is a verb. One "proves" something by producing a "proof". One does not "proof" something anymore than one would "desk" something, or "painting" something. (Admittedly, it is difficult to come up with example nouns that have not been verbed, but I see no reason to verb "proof" when "prove' already has the intended meaning.)